# Manually copied Skyrim Steam Version to new computer, can't start game

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I have manually copied the skyrim directory of steamapps from my old computer to a new one.

After installing Steam again, I tried to copy all files back again to start the game, but, when I start steam, it doesn't recognize Skyrim as installed, and need to download again 10Gb of game. :-/

I didn't know about the Steam Backup feature, so, someone can help me, I think it is a Windows Registry Keys that are missing, but I can't find anything on web related to that!

Any suggests?

Comment: Try to copy it to new folder and then try to install skyrim to that  folder, maybe it will recognise that some files have been downloaded, i don't know if it will work...